# Add data to the fields, only the latter are sent

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

In the form, which has two types of fields added dynamically, only those entered in the last fields are sent after entering the data. The result is to mix up the X and Y values with each other.

For example: I add to the first group of fields x1, x2, x3, to the second group y1, y2, after the draw I get y1:y2, instead of x1:y1, x2:y1, x3:y2, etc.
What am I doing wrong?

Here's my js code:

```
function addDivFormX(){
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.className= 'form-group form-filed horizontal';   

    var input=document.createElement("input");
    input.placeholder='Enter X value';
    input.type='text';
    input.className='input';
    input.autocomplete='off';
    input.name= 'valX';
    input.required=true;
    input.addEventListener("keypress",validate);
    input.addEventListener("keydown", pressEnter);

    newDiv.appendChild(input);
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById("parent");
    parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
    input.focus();
  }
```

For the variable Y it is similar, with the corresponding values changed.

From form.blade:

```
<form method="post" id="form" action="{{route('randomizeVar.store')}}" name="form" 
                class="form text-center" data-response-message-animation="slide-in-left" novalidate>
                   @csrf
                    <div id="parent" class="list-group">
                        <div class="form-group form-filed horizontal">
                            <input name="valX" class="input" type="text" autocomplete="off" 
                            placeholder="Enter X value"  autofocus onkeypress='validate(event)' 
                            onkeydown="pressEnter(event)" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="parent" class="list-group">
                        <div class="form-group form-filed horizontal">
                            <input name="valY" class="input" type="text" autocomplete="off" 
                            placeholder="Enter Y value"  autofocus onkeypress='validate(event)' 
                            onkeydown="pressEnter(event)" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-alternate align-center">Draw</button>                   
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the inputs are using the same `name` attribute. To fix that you must indicate that the data is multiple by setting the names as `valX[]` and `valY[]`.

```
function addDivFormX(){
 ...
 input.name= 'valX[]';
 ...
}
```

```
<input name="valX[]" class="input" type="text" autocomplete="off" 
                            placeholder="Enter X value"  autofocus onkeypress='validate(event)' 
                            onkeydown="pressEnter(event)" required>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, after a few changes, the problem still exists.